# Product flavor specific gradle dependencies on Unity

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, gradle, android-productflavors

Unity offers a custom mainTemplate.gradle file to be used as build.gradle after project export and for dependencies it uses the following;

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
**DEPS**}
```

Problem here is that I have two productFlavors and I want some of the libraries to be product flavor specific.

So the output is;

```
compile(name: 'play-services-plus-10.2.0', ext:'aar')
compile(name: 'play-services-tasks-10.2.0', ext:'aar')
compile(name: 'unity-ads', ext:'aar')
compile project(':gameCircle-2.4.2')
```

What I'm looking for is an output like this;

```
googleCompile(name: 'play-services-plus-10.2.0', ext:'aar')
googleCompile(name: 'play-services-tasks-10.2.0', ext:'aar')
compile(name: 'unity-ads', ext:'aar')
amazonCompile project(':gameCircle-2.4.2')
```

What is the best way to approach this problem?

Thanks in advance